# How do I access a class from Main in console app?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm playing with my first console app -- though I've been developing ASP.NET apps for years.

I see lots of examples where all the simple logic is placed in the Main method. I wanted to create a separate DoSomething.cs class and put my logic in a method called DoThisFirst() then call it from the Main but I can't see the DoThisFirst() method from Main(). What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // I want to call DoThisFirst() method from here. What do I need to do?
    }
}

class DoSomething
{
    static void DoThisFirst()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("It worked!");
       Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you had simply typed the statement `DoSomething.DoThisFirst();` into the `Main()` method and compiled, the compiler would have given you very specific information about what was wrong (i.e. that the method is inaccessible). When in doubt, it's always a good idea to ask the compiler first. You might be amazed at how much it knows about the C# language. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `DoThisFirstis` is `private`, as that is the default accessibility for members of a class.  You'll need to make it public (or at least something more than `private`) to access it from another class.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your response.